# How to set MongoDB profiling level in MongoAtlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

MongoAtlas does not support setting profiling level via GUI.
How can we set the profiling level

Comment: You need to use an user with admin role

Answer (score 1):

We can set profiling level in MongoDB Atlas using Mongo Shell.

1. connect to mongo shell
2. show dbs
3. use
4. db.setProfilingLevel(1)

You can also check Profiling Level

db.getProfilingStatus()